# Mac: How do I get PDF comments or BG colour using Core Graphics

Tags: macos, pdf, core-graphics, osx-yosemite, background-color

We have a application A that outputs PDF data on std::out. The calling application B reads the PDF data and displays it on a window.
The problem is that I need to get the background colour of the PDF to paint the window's background with the same colour. I have the background colour in application A but I am unable to pass it on to B *nicely*. Options are:

1. Set PDF background colour in A, retrieve in B
2. Set the background colour in PDF comment, read the comment in B

For any of the above options, I need some CoreGraphics API calls that I am unable to find. Any ideas on how this can be done?

**UPDATED**
The calling application uses the following calls to draw a PDF (in CFData) on a CGContext:

1. CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData
2. CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider
3. CGPDFDocumentGetPage
4. CGContextDrawPDFPage

Answer (score 0):

The background of a PDF page is just a rectangle filled with some color. So all you need to do is use `CGContextFillRect`. Be sure that this is called before the rest of the PDF is generated (so that it is drawn first) and that you have set the fill color to the color you want. The rectangle should be the size of the page, and should be positioned correctly.

Comment: Thanks but my question is to find some API call that can give me the background colour of a PDF. Preferably in Core Graphics.

Comment: There is no background color in a PDF page. PDFs only have shapes, images and glyphs. Everything is made from those things. When you see a background color, it is because the PDF content stream starts with a page size rectangle filled in a color. How does the calling application display the PDF?

Comment: I have updated the question with the API calls I am using.